# Convert MATLAB file with Nested Structures into a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, excel, matlab, dataframe, struct

I have a MATLAB file with nested structures as shown in the figures below. When I open the file it shows (1,616) struct....Each of the 616 fields have data inside another (1,1) structure. Each (1,1) structure has 6 parameters values of shape (1,789) each.

```
 d = sio.loadmat('file_name.mat')

del d['__header__']
del d['__version__']
del d['__globals__']
d
```

The data when loaded using python, appears as a dictionary with one key (cycle) which has ndarray as values. I want to convert each structure(total 616) which have 6 parameters each into a dataframe and store all the 616 dataframes in a dictionary so that I can convert that dictionary into an excel workbook later. I tried to do for one structure with the following code and got the output as shown below the code(as desired)

```
list1 = d['cycle']['data'].item(0).item(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(list1))
df1 = df1.transpose()
df1.columns = ["Voltage","Current", "Temperature","Current_charger","Voltage_charger","Time"]
df1


Voltage Current Temperature Current_charger Voltage_charger Time
0   3.873017    -0.001201   24.655358   0.000   0.003   0.000
1   3.479394    -4.030268   24.666480   -4.036  1.570   2.532
2   4.000588    1.512731    24.675394   1.500   4.726   5.500
3   4.012395    1.509063    24.693865   1.500   4.742   8.344
4   4.019708    1.511318    24.705069   1.500   4.753   11.125
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
784 4.190822    -0.003391   24.539397   0.000   0.003   7525.782
785 4.191299    -0.000942   24.532498   0.000   0.003   7543.797
786 4.191388    -0.000351   24.518673   0.000   0.003   7561.750
787 4.191453    -0.001856   24.514363   0.000   0.003   7579.813
788 4.191078    -0.002892   24.507040   0.000   0.003   7597.875
789 rows × 6 columns
```

I have done it for one structure. But I am unable to write a code to make it a repetitive thing for all 616 cycles. Please help me out with this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right all you need is to extract the fieldnames of the 6 fields in `B0005.cycle(1).data`.

If they are all named the same across the struct, the task is almost done - you just have to repeat your python code in a for loop for the different `.data`-fields.

If the fieldnames differ, you need to read them first using the MATLAB command

```
fldnames = fieldnames(B0005.cycle(1).data);
```

Then you can save them in a text file, and read/load it in your python script. Then you can go ahead with the code you already have.

Comment: Apologies for a very  late reply....I was not working on this for a while and hence did not check your response.   Yes. You are right. I need to extract the 6 fields from each cycle. But the field names in each cycle are not same. 'Charge' , 'Discharge', 'Impedance' are the 3 cycle names. Each of them has different parameters as field names inside them. I am a beginner here in python. I could not understand what you have explained. It would be great if you can elaborate. Awaiting your response. Thank you :) @Stefan G.

Comment: Ok, my idea was to extract the 6 field names in MATLAB for every struct and save them in a text file. Then you can read this text file in your python script, where you put the lines of code you already have in a for-loop, in order to loop over each field. And then you don't hardcode `df1.columns = [...]` (like you did above), but read the corresponding fieldnames from the text file in each loop dynamically and assign it to `df1.columns`.

Another idea would be to complete the whole task in MATLAB - if that's an option for you. :)